# How can I rename the WordPress AJAX URL?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently looking for a way to change / hide the default WordPress `admin-ajax.php` URL. I want to do this to remove the `admin` from it to prevent misunderstandings by my customers when I use the AJAX URL to read for example a file from my server. In this case, the URL has the admin prefix which is a bit confusing.

So in result the AJAX URl should looks like this: `ajax.php`

I've searched a bit but I can't find any helpful information. Because of this I can't show you any related code. But when I got it, I'll update my question to help other people.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry that it's unclear for you! Maybe you can tell me what you don't understand so that I can improve my question for you. I don't helps me, when you just mark the question for closing without tell my why you did this.

Comment: Do your customers actually _see_ the name of this file? If there are merely using an installation of WP, it will be accessed by the web app in the background, and they won't see it.

Comment: You could create a symlink to it so it has the new name you want, and then search the codebase for the current name, so you can work out how to change it. Of course, don't modify core code directly - always use hooks and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively and perhaps more effectively you could leverage WP API and create a custom endpoint to process your data so that there isn't url confusion.